# Please someone help with this nearly impossible integral

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac{4x^5 -1} {(x^5 + x +1)^2} dx $$

So this is the integral and I have been stuck on it for ages without getting anywhere at all. Nothing I tried has gotten me anywhere so I'm basically stuck on nowhere with this.

I would really love for someone to go through this step by step, that's how I learn the best way. If it is even solvable by a human being....

Comment: @Mathmo123. I hope that with $4x^5+1$, the OP would not have used words such as "nearly impossible integral" or "even solvable by a human being" ! Cheers :)

Comment: Well I am fairly new to calculus and I am not as experienced as you might be

Comment: What I was commenting is that I am sure that, if the numerator had been $4x^5+1$, I am sure you would have recognized $\frac {u'}{u^2}$. Don't worry about being new ! We all have been and we are here to help you.

Comment: $$\frac{4x^5 - 1}{(x^5+x+1)^2} = \frac{(5x^4+1)x-(x^5+x+1)}{(x^5+x+1)^2}
=\left(\frac{-1}{x^5+x+1}\right)'x + \frac{-1}{x^5+x+1}x'
= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{-x}{x^5+x+1}\right)
$$

Comment: @achillehui: Isn't that like working backwards? :P Those steps weren't obvious to me until I checked the final answer from W|A.

Comment: @PranavArora it is not obvious but it isn't something you must need a CAS to figure out.

Comment: @achillehui: Yes, you are right indeed, these type of problems shouldn't require a CAS but converting an integrand to the form $\dfrac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$ is never obvious to me. I always need to seek alternative methods. :(

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Notice that the denominator is a square. So suppose that $$\frac{a+b x}{x^5+x+1}$$ is the antiderivative of $$\frac{4x^5 -1} {(x^5 + x +1)^2}$$ Differentiate the first expression and identify the terms.

I let you finding why the numerator cannot be more complex.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Should i use partial fraction as method?

Comment: OK. Admit that I may have given the trick. So, compute the derivative of my expression and search for which values of $a$ and $b$ you obtain your integrand.

Comment: No partial fractions. Try what I suggest in my comment and come back.

Comment: Did you actually try it yourself? It doesn't seem to work out nicely, and the answer given by Maple doesn't agree either. It looks rather messy, in fact.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen. For sure, I did it (by hand) and the answer is very simple. No need of any CAS.

Comment: Argh, you're right: In my calculation, $a+bx$ morphed into $ax+b$ while its derivative remained as $b$. It seems that $ax+b$ is the canonical first order polynomial in my head. It *is* interesting though, that Maple came up with a complicated answer containing two sums of logarithms, summed over the roots of two different third degree polynomials. These sums must cancel somehow. I guess it shows that CASes can be deceptive.

Comment: Why can't the numerator be more complex?

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{4x^5-1}{(x^5+x+1)^2}\,dx=\int \frac{4x^5+5x^4-5x^4-1}{(x^5+x+1)^2}\,dx$$
$$=\int \frac{4x^5+5x^4}{(x^5+x+1)^2}\,dx-\int \frac{5x^4+1}{(x^5+x+1)^2}\,dx=J_1-J_2$$
$J_2$ can be handled by using the substitution $x^5+x+1=t$ and comes out to be $\dfrac{-1}{x^5+x+1}$. For $J_1$, factor out $x^{5}$ from the expression in parentheses in denominator, i.e:
$$J_1=\int \frac{4x^5+5x^4}{(x^5+x+1)^2}\,dx= \int \frac{\dfrac{4}{x^5}+\dfrac{5}{x^6}}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^4}+\dfrac{1}{x^5}\right)^2}\,dx$$
Now use the substitution $1+\dfrac{1}{x^4}+\dfrac{1}{x^5}=t\Rightarrow -\left(\dfrac{4}{x^5}+\dfrac{5}{x^6}\right)\,dx=dt$, hence
$$J_1=-\int \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{1}{t}+C=\frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1}+C$$
Hence,
$$J_1-J_2=\frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1}+\frac{1}{x^5+x+1}+C=\boxed{\dfrac{x^5+1}{x^5+x+1}+C}$$

Comment: This is very complex, don't you think ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Nope, I don't think so. Rather, its one of the most standard trick which was taught to me in high school. :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is complex but correct. Start from the original integrand, there is no apriori reason it has a simple solution.

Comment: @PranavArora. As achille hui showed, life is simpler.

Comment: I prefer this method ectually, but I have a hard time understanding the factorization of x^5 of J1. I can see that in the denominator you have devided by x^5 but what happens in the numinator is beyond what I understand.

Comment: @user135839: That is simple algebra, I do not see why it is difficult to understand. If you factor out $x^5$ from the expression in parentheses, you get $x^{10}$. Divide the numerator by this $x^{10}$ i.e $4x^5/x^{10}=4/x^5$ and $5x^4/x^{10}=5/x^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I know that this will probably be super wrong but it's what I could come up with

The answere i found was:

$$ -\frac{1 } {x^4}+4log(x+1) -\frac{16x+15}{12x^4}+4x + log(x+1) +4 $$

I used barak manos hint for this

Comment: I am sorry but this is totally wrong.

Comment: Yea, I thought so...